# how to assign x value of M type to option[M]

Tags: scala

I'm trying to assign an x element of type M to option[M] but I'm getting the an error:

```scala
def find(id: Int): Option[M] = dbTable.instances(id)//instances is Map[int,M]
```

```
type mismatch;
[error] found : M
[error] required: Option[M]
[error] def find(id: Int): Option[M] = dbTable.instances(id)
[error] ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 8 s, completed Apr 26, 2019, 1:11:13 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
def find(id: Int): Option[M] = Some(dbTable.instances(id))
```

(or

```
def find(id: Int): Option[M] = Option(dbTable.instances(id))
```

if `dbTable.instances(id)` can be `null`).

If `a` has type `A` then `Some(a)` has type `Option[A]`.

Comment: or `Option(dbTable.instances(id))`, in case of null?

Answer (score 0):

This is supported by Scala Map api with `.get` method.

`def find(id: Int): Option[M] = dbTable.instances.get(id)`